# JSON formatting errors for two files

Tags: php, json, parsing, formatting

I would like to know, I have just created my datatables, but two of them are giving JSON formatting errors.  I am doing a join of two tables in these two.  I tried running the query in phpmyadmin, and it works just fine Here is one example of my server-side files:

```
<?php
$username="drup197";
$password="*****";
$database="census";
$server="localhost";

$link = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);

//@mysql_select_db($database,$link) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query = "
    SELECT *   
    FROM national_age_gender_demographics INNER JOIN arizona_age_gender_demogrpahics
    WHERE national_age_gender_demographics.age_group = arizona_age_gender_demogrpahics.age_group
    ORDER BY national_age_gender_demographics.index_number";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

if(!$result)  die( "Query: " . $query . "\nError:" . mysql_error() );

//print_r($row);
$tableData = '{"aaData": [[';
$numRows = $result->num_rows;
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

for ($i = 0; $i < $numRows; $i++) {
    if ($i != 0) {
        $tableData .= ",[";
    }
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['age_group'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['national_age_gender_demographics.both_pop'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['national_age_gender_demographics.male_pop'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['national_age_gender_demographics.female_pop'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['national_age_gender_demographics.male_percent'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['national_age_gender_demographics.female_percent'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['national_age_gender_demographics.both_percent'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['national_age_gender_demographics.males_per_100_females'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['arizona_age_gender_demographics.both_pop'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['arizona_age_gender_demographics.male_pop'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['arizona_age_gender_demographics.female_pop'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['arizona_age_gender_demographics.male_percent'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['arizona_age_gender_demographics.female_percent'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['arizona_age_gender_demographics.both_percent'] . '",';
    $tableData .= '"' . $row['arizona_age_gender_demographics.males_per_100_females'] . '"]';
    if ($i != $numRows - 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    }
}
$tableData .= ']}';
echo $tableData;
?>
```

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: Why are you trying to build the JSON array yourself? Why don't you use the PHP built in functions `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` for this?

Comment: or if those functions not available, download the PEAR version

Comment: Re:SV

It worked just fine when using a single table.  However, I am specifically having trouble when I join two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Steven is right, its better to use the json encode (or at least neater) to create your json, save you from the messy ifs and bracket business.

I would also recommend using mysqli_fetch_assoc rather than using mysqli_fetch_array, which as you currently specified should return both associative and numbered results (see here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php), which probably messes up your results.

eg:

```
...
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$json_data = json_encode($row);
echo $json_data;
?>
```

Try that and see how you get on?

Comment: Actually, I have found the error myself - I spelled "demographics" wrong in a few places in the query.  While I am no longer getting the error, the rows end up blank.  Could anyone help me here?

FYI, I tried using the above method as well, but the processing and loading gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: With the correct query, how many rows are returned? you could find this out by echoing $numRows = $result->num_rows;

Comment: Guess I was wrong, I am still getting the error.  However, when using your method, on closer inspection, I am getting the following JavaScript error:
Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference:
jquery.dataTables.min.js, line 59 character 74

Comment: Looks like a javascript issue, I would first test the json output is valid (just hit the page to output the above json) and as expected. Then double check your JS is all working, and you have included jquery before you include the dataTables script.

Comment: FYI, when using my method, it looks like I am getting undefined index errors when accessing the PHP file directly.  I will ask this in a new question.